# Swift UITableViewCell subview do not register tap

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uitapgesturerecognizer

**Background:** I'm making a calendar and for that I'm combining a UITableView and a UICollectionViews. The UITableView is holding month cells. Each month UITableViewCell is holding a UICollectionView with UICollectionViewCell days.

**Problem:** The UICollectionViewCells aren't clickable. 
I can fix this by calling self.bringSubviewToFront(self.collectionView) in the month UITableViewCell. However this makes the UITableView not scroll because the collectionView is now top view.

So, I can either choose between be able to scroll the UITableView or be able to click the UICollectionView.

**What I tried:** I tried to capture the click before it happens and bring the collectionView to front and then put it back again. Not a good solution though:

```
//In UITableViewCell class

//UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
//Bring collectionView to front before tap
override func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,  shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    self.bringSubviewToFront(self.collectionView)
    return true
}

//UIScrollViewDelegate
//Bring collectionView to back again
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.sendSubviewToBack(self.collectionView)
    //Do stuff
}
```

**Question:** How can I achieve to both be able to scroll and have the UICollectionView clickable without bringing back and forward the view between taps? Is there a way to have the UICollectionView in front and still make the UITableView scrollable?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What the scroll directions for both your tableview and collection view?

Comment: Of course!! self.collectionView.scrollEnabled = false solved it, thaank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested UIScrollView with same scroll directions is against Apple's Human Interface Guidelines and your app might even get rejected for this so try disabling the scroll of your UICollectionView.

Hope this helps.

Comment: self.collectionView.scrollEnabled = false solved it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help. All the best.